# reading string and integers from file

Tags: c

I have been trying to read some strings and integers from a file,but it seems that I don't do it correctly...This programm is supposed to read data from a file...It must create a list with the names of writters.For every writter,it should use a struct like the one I used here...Foe every writter's text,I must also create a struct,like the one I did here..Then,I have to sort the list,create another list with the most popular writers and then print the output...My program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct AuthorRecord {   
    char textTitle[30];  
    long Download;       
    struct AuthorRecord *next;                 
  };
  typedef struct AuthorRecord *AuthorRecordType;
  typedef struct {
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];  
    int idNumber,s1;
    long s2; 
    float p;
    AuthorRecordType text;
  } AuthorType;
 struct MemberNodeStruct {
    AuthorType *anAuthor;
    struct MemberNodeStruct *next;
  };
  typedef struct MemberNodeStruct *MemberNodeType;

int main()
{

 int m,n,i,j,d,z,e,y;    
  long k;   
  char s[30];
  AuthorType *a;
  struct MemberNodeStruct *l,*l2,*temp,*min,*b1,*b2,*r,*r2,*r3;
  struct AuthorRecord *t,*t2,*h,*h2,*min2,*temp2;
  FILE *f;
  f=fopen("project.txt","rt");     
  if(f==NULL)
    exit(-1);
  l2=NULL;
  t2=NULL;
  t=NULL;
  fscanf(f,"%d",&n); 
  getchar();      
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
     y=0;              
    a=(AuthorType*)malloc(sizeof( AuthorType)); 
    fgets(s,30,f);                        
    strcpy(a->firstName,s);
    fgets(s,30,f);                
    strcpy(a->lastName,s);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&d);
    getchar();
    a->idNumber=d;                            
    fscanf(f,"%d",&m);
    getchar();                       
    t2=NULL;
    a->s1=m;
    a->s2=0;                                 
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
    {
      t=(struct AuthorRecord*)malloc(sizeof(struct AuthorRecord));       
      fgets(s,30,f);                                                
      e=0;                 
        h=t2;                                                 
      while(e==0 && h!=NULL)
      {
        if(strcmp(h->textTitle,s)==0)
        {
          e=1;
          h2=h;   
        }
        else
          h=h->next;
      }
      if(e==0)                        
      {
       strcpy( t->textTitle,s);
        fscanf(f,"%ld",&k);
        getchar();             
        t->Download=k;
        a->s2=a->s2+t->Download;       
        t->next=t2;
        t2=t;
          }
      else
      {
          y=y+1;
        fscanf(f,"%ld",&k);
        getchar();
        h2->Download=h2->Download+k;  
        a->s2=a->s2+k;              
      }
    }
    a->s1=a->s1-y;
    a->p=round(a->s2/a->s1);       
    a->text=t2;
    l=(struct MemberNodeStruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct MemberNodeStruct));   
    l->anAuthor=a;                                                         
    l->next=l2;
    l2=l;
  }




........  (150 more lines of code)
.....
system("pause")
return(0);
```

I have tried this program with `scanf` and gets instead of a file and `fscanf` and `fgets` and it worked correctly...That's the reason I don't write the rest of my code.

project.txt is:

```
5
Julius Caesar 101
2
DeBelloGallico
3000
DeBelloCivili
8000
Sun Tzu 544
3
TheArtOfWar
5000
TheArtOfWar
5000
Strategems
3000
Plato Athenian 427
4
TrialOfSocrates
10000
Symposium
15000
TheRepublic
7000
Apology
9000
Gaius Suetonius 69
3
thetwelvecaesars
7000
dePoetis
500
DeClarisRhetorebus
1000
Orestis Mastakas 1995
1
WhyDidRomePrevail
15
```

Whenever I run this program,it ends up in a failure...For some reason,it demands input from me...I tried to remove the getchar() but still, it didn't work! What should I do?

Comment: Debugging the program often helps.

Comment: Well,I tried to debug it,but i failed...I have lost more than 30 hours trying to make this programm work..!But still,I don't know what's wrong with it...!

Comment: C's not the language I'd choose to solve this problem, but if you're doing this to learn then don't worry.

Comment: It's very difficult to debug your code since you have member variables and function variables that are not descriptive. How the hell is one supposed to make sense of variable names used in `struct MemberNodeStruct *l,*l2,*temp,*min,*b1,*b2,*r,*r2,*r3;`??

Comment: 1) Robust code would check the results of `fscanf()` and `fgets()`as part of the normal coding.  This code ignores those result at its peril.  2) Further strongly recommend to only use `fgets()` to read the line, then use `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, `strtok()`, etc. to parse the line.

Comment: I finally managed to correct my code...I just deleted all of the getchar lines and I replaced fgets with fscanf...!I would like to thank everyone for spending his/her time trying to help me...!The next time a encounter a C problem,I will definitely know the place I can find help...!

Answer (score 2):

It reads input from stdin, because you told it to do that :

```
fscanf(f,"%d",&n); 
getchar();
```

Try making sure, you don't have anything reading input from default (file descriptor 0).
If you need to read 1 char from `f`, then use fgetc instead of getchar.

Comment: or `fscanf(f,"%d%*c",&n);`

Comment: That's right...!getchar() was indeed a problem!Thank you for your help!!But still,instead of a normal output,I get some random symbols and letters...Is fscanf responsible for this?

Comment: Write a tiny program to check that fscanf works how you think it's meant to :)  Then try reading in one author, checking that's right, then try 3 authors and see if sort works.